# SVN multiple repositories in subfolders

Tags: svn, apache, multiple-repositories

I'm using apache+svn

apache config file:

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /code>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath "c:/repositories"
</Location>
```

Imagine i have this file structure (in every t? i have one svn repository)

```
c
    repositories
        uc1
            0809v
                t1
                t2
                t3
            0809i
                t1
                t2
        uc2
            t1
            t2
        t1
```

I can access the repositories using:

```
svn://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t1  
svn://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t2  
svn://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t3
```

I want to access them using the urls:

```
http://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t1  
http://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t2  
http://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t3
```

and see the content of the repository in the browser.

If i create the repository on the root of the svn folder i can see the repository (http://domain.com/code/t1) when i try the other urls i get the error **Could not open the requested SVN filesystem**

My question is,
It is possible to do a search in all subfolders looking for svn repositories?

**Edit**

> The [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) states that the directories under SVNParentPath have
>   to be repositories, so no looking
>   through all subdirectories.
>
> You might be able to make script
>   though, that would output several
>   Location-blocks matching the parent
>   folders of SVN repositories.

With this solution given by https://serverfault.com/users/24957/ptman do i have to restart apache every time i create a new repository !?

Comment: I don't have any clue what you are actually asking, I've set up a lot of svn repositories in my day before and could probably help you if you asked the question more clearly.  Also, you should be posting this on serverfault, not stackoverflow

Comment: I can just access repositories located in a subfolder of my repositories folder. I want to have access to repositories with depth greater than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by https://serverfault.com/users/24957/ptman in https://serverfault.com/questions/135459/svn-multiple-repositories-in-subfolders

> The documentation states that the
>   directories under SVNParentPath have
>   to be repositories, so no looking
>   through all subdirectories.
>
> You might be able to make script
>   though, that would output several
>   Location-blocks matching the parent
>   folders of SVN repositories.

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/96113/read-only-svn-on-apache2-under-windows